# How does one specify type (typeScript) on injected properties through withRouter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-router

I am quite new to TypeScript and I am trying to create a component that is wrapped in a "withRouter" HOC (through the npm-package [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter))to receive props such as match, history and location. How does one properly do this? Can I import a ready made interface from [@types/react-router-dom](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts)? Below is my first attempt:

```
import classes from './SomeComponent.module.scss';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

interface SomeComponentProps {}

interface WithRouter {
  match: ObjectWithAnyKeys;
  location: ObjectWithAnyKeys;
  history: ObjectWithAnyKeys;
}

interface ObjectWithAnyKeys {
  [s: string]: string;
}

export const SomeComponent: React.FunctionComponent<SomeComponentProps & WithRouter> = ({
  match,
  location,
  history,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.ReadActivityContainer}>
      {'Some component that uses the router props match, location and history'}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(SomeComponent as any);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just import these prop type from lib

```
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

than you have to say that your component has these props

```
type ownProps = {}
export const SomeComponent: React.FunctionComponent<ownProps & RouteComponentProps> = (props: ownProps & RouteComponentProps) => {
  const history = props.history;
  const match = props.match;
  // ect... all in props
  return (
    <div>
      some component that uses the router props match, location and history
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

Comment: Splendid answer, thank you for that. One question though, how does one know this? I scowered the internet and found nothing, any tips on how to solve these issues in the future? Also - what type does one use for JSX? Sometime I have functions that return JSX to be able to handle complex conditional formatting in functional components, but I never know what to use

Comment: Well, i am pretty sure this question was already answered somewhere. You have just search more. It is standard that HOC will pass some props to your component. go check definition of "withRouter" you will see what prop there are. alslo you can see these props are interface that is exported so you can import it. and i dont understand your question about jsx

Comment: regarding JSX - let's say I have a funtion that has a return statement:
`return (<div><SomeComponent /></div>)`
What would be the return-type of that function?

Comment: check in typescript. it says it is JSX.Element. Interface from react lib. JSX is namespace where there are a lot of interfaces. if you dont know what type  you should use, you can always go to definition in typescript.